# Deploying a Postgres app to Heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

This is my first time deploying to Heroku so I will try to make this question as clear as possible.  I am trying to deploy a simple app to Heroku for practice.  I had this working locally but not sure what else I need to change in my code.

Changes made so far:

1) Rebuilt my DB connection (was set up for local host)

```
var dbUrl = 
var dbUser =
var dbPass = 
var dbHost = 
var dbName =

const db = new sequelize(dbName, dbUser, dbPass, {
    host: dbHost,
    dialect: 'postgres'
})
```

2) Rebuilt the server connection listener.

```
//Sever connection to port 3k WITH HEROKU connection.
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// app.use(express.static('public'))

const listener = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server has started at ', listener.address().port)
})
```

3) Added a start object to package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
```

I am lost on what I need to do next.  Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you provisioned the free heroku postgres database addon?
I'm working in python and have to do `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev`. There should be a similar command for node.js.

Comment: Thanks.  I will look into that now.